# Downloading zip or tar.gz inside Wordpress installation?

Tags: htaccess, errors, 404-error

I have WP installed in root dir, e.g., `public_html/`

I make a non-wordpress site here `public_html/other/`

HTML files are accessible just fine, e.g, `http://example.com/other/index.html` however downloadable files are being overridden by Wordpress 404 pages. E.g., Accessing `http://example.com/other/download.tar.gz` doesn't trigger a download but instead shows a Wordpress 404.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: In your WordPress .htaccess, you could use a rule lke: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/other/`

Comment: Can you check the permissions of your file? Make sure that has global permissions to READ. I got the same problem and I fixed changing the permissions from my file to (444).